# How does Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() return the userEmail of another person who has access to the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

we are developer and creating integration of spreadsheet with salesforce to sync reords.
but unable to get user email who is chnahing the records.

how can we get the email address. we are providing them access as editor.
why Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() reurns empty string. what we can do to get email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail), for security reasons `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` sometimes returns `null`. For example, when a script runs in a context that does not require user's authorization, like simple `onEdit` and `onOpen` triggers.

Exception: when the developer of the script and users running it belong to the same Google Workspace domain.

I assume you are running the script via a simple `onEdit` trigger and users do not belong to the same  Google Workspace domain. You cannot get their emails under these circumstances.

Comment: It means.. If all editors and the owner belong to the same Workspace domain, then my issue will be resolved. and then I will be able to access email addresses via the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() method. Am i right?

Comment: @PremKumar Yes, this is how it should work.